# Entry point not found with 32bits DLL. Working with 64 bits DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cuda, 32bit-64bit

Our team developped a C++ CUDA DLL and a C# .NET 4.5 HMI which uses our DLL.

These programs were initially planed to be available only for 64bits platform.

Recently our client ask us to make our developpements available for 32bits platform too.

We manage to compile the DLL and the HMI in 32bits.

So we have now 2 configurations :

- **HMI x64 which uses CUDA DLL x64**
- **HMI x86 which uses CUDA DLL x86**

**The 64bits configuration works perfectly.**

**The 32bits configuration has some problems :**

- Only some exported functions are available
- Unvailable functions calls throw exception : **Entry point not found < name > in < Dllname >**

Exploring our 32 and 64bits dll with *Dependency Walker* shows us all the exported functions. (Only mangled names change between 32 & 64bits)

Here are some prototypes of available exported functions :

```
extern "C" RetourInit __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall initGPU();
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall setImageGpu(int idGPU, int nbImages, Image * listeImages);
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall getImageGpu(int idGPU, int nbImages, Image * listeImages);
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall duplicateImage(int idGPU, int nbImages, Image * listeImages);
```

Here are some prototypes of unavailable exported functions :

```
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall decoupe(int idCarte, Decoupe paramDecoupe);
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall fusion(int idCarte, Fusion paramFusion);
```

If you have any solution to propose or questions we will be glad to hear it.

Thanks all.

Comment: My guess is that the Decoupe and Fusion types have some dependency that is tied to a 64-bit implementation.  The other exported functions are using vanilla types.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Here are structures used in the decoupe prototype :

`struct Decoupe{
 Image image;
 int nbBandes;
 Bande * bandes;
};`

`struct Image{
 unsigned char * ptr; 
 int largeur;
 int hauteur; 
 int bpp; 
 int tailleOctets; 
};`

`struct Bande{
 unsigned char * ptr;
 int largeur;
 int hauteur;
 int bpp;
 int pasX;
 int pasY;
 int posX;
 int posY;
 bool horizontale;
 bool reversed;
};`

I don't see any 64bits dependency implementation.
If you have any other solution, I'll be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to passing Fusion & Decoupe structures not with pointer.

We just change our prototypes to this :

```
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall decoupe(int idCarte, Decoupe* paramDecoupe);
extern "C" Retour __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall fusion(int idCarte, Fusion* paramFusion);
```

And adapt our DLL code. Our C# HMI hasn't be changed.

This modification **works in x86 & x64**.

It's very weird that 64bits platform isn't impacted by this modification...

Thanks for your comments.